# while x and y are within certain limits

Tags: python, while-loop, random-walk

Im trying to write a random walk sim where the field size is limited to 10 x 10 m.
My idea was to limit x and y to -10 to +10 in a while loop, but it does not work. x and/or y keeps getting bigger than 10 or less than -10.

I have tried to break up the while loop parameters to something easier but it still didnt work

what am i doing wrong?

```
def move(self, steps):

    global lastStep
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0


    while -10 <= x <= 10 and -10 <= y <= 10 :

            for i in range(steps):
                # print("before field test; ", x, y)
                step = random.choice(['N', 'W', 'S', 'E'])
                if step == 'N':
                    y += 0.5
                elif step == 'S':
                    y -= 0.5
                elif step == 'E':
                    x += 0.5
                elif step == 'W':
                    x -= 0.5
                else:
                    raise ValueError ("In Drunk.move")
                lastStep = step

            return x, y

    return x, y
```

Comment: Change the `while` to an `if ...: break` and move it inside the `for` loop?

Comment: The first `return` statement effectively turns your `while` loop into an `if` statement; remove it.